# Python3, how to encode this string correctly?

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, python-3.5

*disclaimer, I've already done a long research to solve that alone but most of the questions I found here concern Python 2.7 or doesn't solve my problem*

Let's say I've the following (That example comes from BeautifulSoup doc, I'm trying to solve a bigger issue):

```
>>> markup = "<h1>Sacr\xc3\xa9 bleu!</h1>"
>>> print(markup)
'SacrÃ© bleu!'
```

For me, markup should be assigned to a bytes, so I could do:

```
>>> markup = b"<h1>Sacr\xc3\xa9 bleu!</h1>"
>>> print(str(markup, 'utf-8'))
<h1>Sacré bleu!</h1>
```

Yeah ! but how do I do that transition between `"<h1>Sacr\xc3\xa9 bleu!</h1>"` which is wrong into `b"<h1>Sacr\xc3\xa9 bleu!</h1>"` ?

Because if I do:

```
>>> markup = b"<h1>Sacr\xc3\xa9 bleu!</h1>"
>>> bytes(markup, "utf-8")
b'<h1>Sacr\xc3\x83\xc2\xa9 bleu!</h1>'
```

You see? It inserted `\x83\xc2` for free.

```
>>> print(bytes(markup))
TypeError: string argument without an encoding
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the Unicode string `"<h1>Sacr\xc3\xa9 bleu!</h1>"`, something has already gone wrong. Either your input is broken, or you did something wrong when processing it. For example, here, you've copied a Python 2 example into a Python 3 interpreter.

If you have your broken string because you did something wrong to get it, then you should really fix whatever it was you did wrong. If you need to convert `"<h1>Sacr\xc3\xa9 bleu!</h1>"` to `b"<h1>Sacr\xc3\xa9 bleu!</h1>"` anyway, then encode it in latin-1:

```
bytestring = broken_unicode.encode('latin1')
```

Comment: indeed, I'm aware it is already broken, I've this issue with BeautifulSoup, I tried to keep the question clear by isolating the problem, thank you for your answer